# .htaccess to redirect from http to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website on shared host, the hosting default root directory is */public_html*, but I place my website at */pulbic_html/web* for file organizing purpose

I have registered for HTTPS from cloudflare

**I wish for 2 results**

1. visitors can type https://example.com, https://www.example.com
2. visitors can type http://example.com, http://www.example.com then redirect to either https://example.com or https://www.example.com

My current *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Using the current .htaccess

1. typing http://example.com -> working
2. typing http://www.example.com -> working
3. typing https://example.com -> working
4. typing https://www.example.com -> working but redirect to http://example.com with **connection not secure** warning on the browser

I have googled and came up with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

with this .htaccess all testing result

[image]

**please help** to achieve these

1. typing https://example.com, https://www.example.com -> working
2. typing http://example.com, http://www.example.com -> redirect to either https://example.com or https://www.example.com

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help.. Update your current rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Replace your rewrite rule with this.. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule  "put new rule here"